# Next-auth.js - How do I redirect from getServerSideProps with a callback url?

Tags: javascript, next.js, next-auth

I'm using the NextAuth library for authentication in a Next.js app and I've come across a scenario which hasn't been addressed in the docs. I'm trying to add a 'route guard' if you can call it that by checking if session is not null in *getServerSideProps* and redirecting to the built in signin page. Although that works, I'm always redirected to the home page after signing in. I tried to add the callbackUrl query parameter as you can see below but it still doesn't work as expected. How do I achieve this? Thanks in advance.

blog.js

```
export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  const session = await getSession(context)
  if (!session) {
    return {
      redirect: {
        destination: `/api/auth/signin?callbackUrl=${encodeURIComponent(
          'http:localhost:3000/blog'
        )}`,
        permanent: false
      }
    }
  }
  return {
    props: {
      data: 'Blog data',
      session
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you the codevolution Vishwas?

Answer (score 1):

Now that your login page has a query string:

1. You need to pull the callbackUrl from url (I would suggest giving it a good default such as "/dashboard")
2. You need to pass a callbackURL to your signIn function (that I assume you are calling instead of a post method) from your onSubmit function.

```
const { query:{ callbackUrl } } = useRouter(); 

signIn("your-provider-name", {
        ...logInFormValues, // such as email and password
        callbackUrl, // from the useRouter hook
      });
```